# How to choose a running shoe when you weigh 80-85kg?

Tags: running, long-distance-running, running-shoes, shoes

I've read a little bit about shoes for running on asphalt and for trail-running, but they always refer to lightweight people. I would like to know what to look for in a running shoe when my weight is between 80 and 85 kilograms?

Comment: I'm 75kg and use Asics when I go running. My training buddy is 110kg and uses the same shoes. Neither one of us has had any problems.

Comment: 80kg doesn't sound that much, depending on your height.  You should be careful with your joints if you consider yourself to be overweight, as running surely puts more strain on them than walking.

Comment: 80 kilos is not much. I currently ay 87 kilos and I use regular New Balance shoes for running.

Answer (score 4):

The best thing you could probably do would be to find a dedicated runner's shop. We've got one where I live and they are really specializing in running shoes.

A good runner's shop should be able to do several things for you:

- There should be trained employees, who are themselves runners (or do
  sports at least) and know what they do.
- They can assess your current fitness status,
  pronation/supination issues, intended running surface etc.
- Some even have a treadmill analysis, where your running style is examined

It might be hard to find a shop like that, but it's really worth it once you do.
And don't skimp on it just because the shoes cost a bit more, your joints will thank you.